# User_Notify on Phpbb Notifies ALL Members

Tags: mysql, database, forum, phpbb

I am currently having an issue with my phpbb forum system. I set all the users value for "user_notify" to 1, which should make phpbb send a notification email to the user telling them somebody responded to your thread. However, it turns out that phpbb is sending emails to EVERYBODY registered on the forum about that reply somebody made. Would anybody know how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue, and I would like to share what I have found because I am sure there are others that are having this issue.

There is a MOD for phpbb called Board Watch. If it is installed then the user_notify field in your phpbb_users mysql table will serve a different function. By default Board Watch will make phpbb email everybody about any activity at all that happens on the board. I simply uninstalled Board Watch and kept my default value for user_notify to 1. Now, it emails only the person who made the thread of a notification or the person who has replied to the thread.